# onClick OverlayView react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I can't understand why the `onclick` in the `OverlayView` doens't work. I've put a custom object (a simply div) as child, is the `BaloonLocationJob`.

How can make the `OverlayView` clickable?

```
<GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={16}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: props.job.latitude, lng: props.job.longitude }}
        options={{mapTypeControl:false,navigationControl:false,streetViewControl:false,scaleControl:false}}>
        {
            <OverlayView
                key={Math.random()}
                position={{ lat: props.job.latitude, lng: props.job.longitude }}
                onClick={props.hello}
                mapPaneName={OverlayView.OVERLAY_LAYER}>
                <BaloonLocationJob address={props.job.address} onClick={props.onToggleOpen/* todo: this isn't working*/}/>
            </OverlayView>
        }
</GoogleMap>
```

Comment: I don't think `OverlayView` can have a `onClick` prop, but the component inside of it can. Doesn't `onClick={props.onToggleOpen}` work?

Comment: unfortunally this was my first try.. onclick in the child element doesn't work neither

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. It was my fault, I didn't read properly the doc. 
I just changed the mapPaneName prop in the OverlayView component:

```
    <OverlayView
            key={Math.random()}
            position={{ lat: props.job.latitude, lng: props.job.longitude }}
            mapPaneName={OverlayView.OVERLAY_LAYER}>
            <BaloonLocationJob address={props.job.address}  onClick={props.onToggleOpen}/>
        </OverlayView>
```

to:

```
    <OverlayView
            key={Math.random()}
            position={{ lat: props.job.latitude, lng: props.job.longitude }}
            mapPaneName={OverlayView.OVERLAY_MOUSE_TARGET}>
            <BaloonLocationJob address={props.job.address}  onClick={props.onToggleOpen}/>
        </OverlayView>
```